# What version of Numpy does TensorFlow 1.19.5 require?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I've installed Keras and TensorFlow 1.19.5 and have numpy version 1.19.5. I got this error warning when I installed TensorFlow:

```
FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
```

I also got this warning:

```
frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.9
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 880, got 864
```

Is this error related to the version of TensorFlow I am using?

Comment: Did you install tf from pip or is it from a different build? Can you also share which version of Python you are using?

Comment: Yes, I used pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl, and I am using Python 3.9.1

Comment: I used "pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl"
rather than  rather than "pip install --upgrade tensorflow", as when I used that I got an error message saying that a version of tensorflow could not be found

Comment: TF doesn't support Py 3.9 in mac yet. See this link- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485#issuecomment-720675069

`frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.9` warning is due to that. If there is no requirement to use Python 3.9, either downgrade it or use a conda virtual env.  I suggest using conda virtual env with Python 3.7. The Numpy warning is because you are using 1.19.5. You can install Numpy 1.16.4 to avoid this warning.

Comment: Let me know if you are stuck, I can give a detailed answer.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.4.1 version supports Numpy version 1.19.5. `pip install tensorflow` installs latest version of Tensorflow. Current stable version 2.4.1.